# how to reuse code in same script in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to create a oracle sql script (not stored procedure) which has some sql statements (***process_audit sql statements***) that are getting used more than once in the script.

Pseudo code of my oracle script:

```
begin
open cursor1
loop(1)
open cursor2
loop(2)
if codition1 then
     process_audit sql statements;
 else
 sql statements;
 end if;
 end loop(2); 
 close cursor2;
  end loop(1);
   close cursor2;
    process_audit sql statements;
  end;
```

In Java/C we can create a function and put the reusable lines in it and then call the function wherever it is required.
Can we do similar in oracle sql script?
I cannot use function as I cannot create anything permanently in the database schema.

Comment: You can create functions in oracle also Refer http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_function.htm.

Comment: What do you mean with "not PL/SQL"? PL/SQL _is_ the procedural language used for writing Oracle functions, procedures etc. (anything you cannot do with SQL alone).

Comment: If I used function then the funcion will be created permanently in the database, and I don't want create anything in the database.

Comment: You could create an [anonymous PL/SQL block](http://psoug.org/reference/anonymous_blocks.html) which you execute and wrap as a function in your client language (shell script, Java, etc.).

Comment: Why don't you want to create it in the database? You can expect performance issues if you don't

Answer (score 3):

Put common part of code in inner procedure (or function) in declare section in PLSQL block and run it like here:

```
declare
  var number := 0;

  procedure process_audit is
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line(var);
  end;

begin
  var := var + 10;
  process_audit;
  var := var * 5;
  process_audit;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `procedure and function` in `plsql` block, which won't created in the `schema`:
**Demo**

```
-- Declarative part of block begins
DECLARE
  -- variable declaration
  in_string  VARCHAR2(100);
  out_string VARCHAR2(200);

  -- Procedure declaration and definition begins
  PROCEDURE pseudo_proc(
     original IN VARCHAR2,
     new_string OUT VARCHAR2 
     --more params ...
  )
  IS
    BEGIN
      --your pseudo code
    EXCEPTION
      --handle exception
    END;
    -- Procedure declaration and definition ends
BEGIN
  pseudo_proc(in_string, out_string);  -- Procedure invocation
  pseudo_proc(in_string, out_string);  -- Procedure invocation
  pseudo_proc(in_string, out_string);  -- Procedure invocation
  -- any no of times.....
END;
-- Executable part of block ends
/
```

Please refer [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#CHDBIEEE)

Note: all other variables should be declared above `procedure or function` declaration.